# Quiero traer una variable de php y que sea la definición de un src iframe en html

Tags: php, html, iframe, src

Llevo un par de semanas desarrollando a una app web para un coro católico al cual pertenezco, he hecho un formulario para captura de la información de los datos, ya conecté la base de datos y he logrado hacer la consulta para poder seleccionar la ruta en donde se encuentra el canto, pero ahora tengo un problema, en el archivo de html necesito que en el iframe el src="" tome el valor de dicha consulta, es decir si el resultado de la consulta es "Cantos/EN0001.html" ese sea el valor valor que sea reemplaza en el src del iframe, las lineas de código que tengo son las siguientes:

```
<section id="entrada" class="entrada">
        <h1 class="container">Entrada</h1>
        <iframe id="mostrar" class="encuentro" src=""></iframe>
    </section>

    <?php

    include("conexion.php")

    $sql2 = "SELECT Entrada FROM `Repertorio` WHERE id= (SELECT MAX(id) from Repertorio);";
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2);

    if ($resultado2) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
        $Entrada = $fila['Entrada'];
        if ($Entrada) {
            iframe.src=$Entrada;
        }
?>
```

Comment: Haz primero la parte de PHP. Con eso ya tendrás el valor que necesitas y podrás ponerlo en el iframe.

Comment: Ok, pero el código de php está correcto @Jakala ... Gacias por responder.

Comment: No digo que sea erróneo. Digo que cambies de orden las cosas: primero llama a BBDD para obtener lo que necesitas. Después ya puedes construir tu html con ese valor en el iframe

Comment: <section id="entrada" class="entrada">
            <h1 class="container">Entrada</h1>
            <iframe id="mostrar" class="encuentro" src=" <?php echo $Entrada ?> "> </iframe>
    </section>

Comment: eso es, cambiando el codigo de orden ya tienes acceso a la informacion.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar de esta manera:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Entrada FROM `Repertorio` WHERE id= (SELECT MAX(id) from Repertorio);";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2);

if ($resultado2) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
        $Entrada = $fila['Entrada'];
```

y asi reemplace en el src del iframe

```
<section id="entrada" class="entrada">
        <h1 class="container">Entrada</h1>
        <iframe id="mostrar" class="encuentro" src=" <?php echo $Entrada ?> "> </iframe>
</section>
```

Comment: Hola. Sí esperas una sola fila no necesitas usar `while`. Sí esperas varias filas úsalo, pero en ese caso debes concatenar o ir imprimiendo dentro del `while`.